# Error executing stdev.s excel formula in Java

Tags: java, excel

I need to execute the following excel formula in java:

```
STDEV.S(A1:A3)
```

This is how I implemented it.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ExcelTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
        row1.createCell(0).setCellValue(5);

        Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
        row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(10);
        
        Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);
        row3.createCell(0).setCellValue(20);

        CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = creationHelper.createFormulaEvaluator();
        Cell stdevsCell = row2.createCell(1); 
        
        stdevsCell.setCellFormula("STDEV.S(A1:A3)");

        formulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(stdevsCell);

        double result = stdevsCell.getNumericCellValue();

        workbook.close();
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell Sheet0!B2
...
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: STDEV.S
```

Seems STDEV.S is not available in org.apache.poi.ss.

Any suggested way to achieve this then?